# question regarding use of MySQL triggers

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have seen MySQL triggers mentioned and I am curious whether they could be used for my scenario. That being:

lets say i have a table `results_tb`. Currently there is a field `score` and a field `grade` . So can I use triggers to update grade on the event of score changing?

so for example, lets say score stored was 40, the grade is updated to C, then again if the score is updated to 70, the grade is updated to A.

is this possible with triggers?

Comment: if your grade is derived from score, I don't see why to store grade, I'd instead use a function. IMO this kind of logic shouldn't be stored on the DB level though

Comment: well I just wanted the grade there for exporting the records.

Comment: you can export fields that aren't on the table, just create a function that calculates the grade and then you can do like SELECT score, calcGrade(score) FROM ... take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: ye i know i can do that, i just kinda wanted to use triggers, to really just learn something new. but thanks though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a trigger if you want, however, I agree with Nanne in terms of what appears to be better approach in the situation described.

```
DELIMITER |

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `trigger_update_results_tb`|

CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_update_results_tb` BEFORE UPDATE ON `results_tb` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
       CASE FLOOR(NEW.score / 10)
        WHEN 0 THEN SET NEW.grade = 'F';
        WHEN 1 THEN SET NEW.grade = 'F';
        WHEN 2 THEN SET NEW.grade = 'F';
        WHEN 3 THEN SET NEW.grade = 'F';
        WHEN 4 THEN SET NEW.grade = 'D';
        WHEN 5 THEN SET NEW.grade = 'C';
        WHEN 6 THEN SET NEW.grade = 'B';
        ELSE SET NEW.grade = 'A';
       END CASE;
    END;
|

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Hi Brian, I'm not familiar with triggers, but will it go over every row of the table every time you update any row of the table? Does "for each row" mean for each modified row or for each row of the table? Thanks in advance

Comment: FOR EACH ROW BEGIN will go over each row that has been modified by whatever SQL statement was executed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could create a `trigger` that fires on 'update'. The [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) is quite clear. But you would have to make some sort of "list" of grades that correspond with your scores. So you'd have something of a list that compares scores to grades. That sounds suspiciously like a "lookup table" to me.

Couldn't you just add a table for grades that belong to a certain score to your database, and if you query your current `results_tb`, add a `join` to that table?

So instead of

```
SELECT score, grade FROM results_tb WHERE id=1
```

you'd get

```
SELECT r.score, l.grade FROM results_tb r 
JOIN lookup l ON r.score = l.score
WHERE r.id=1
```